# What does "we’ll see about that" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am a nurse at a hospital, and I was cyber chatting with this girl who has just told me that her mother is being treated for a chronic illness at the same hospital. Our conversation went like this:

> ME - Hope she gets better and you’ll never ever have to see me or that hospital again
>
> GIRL-Thanks. Hospital. Yeah. You. We’ll see about that :)

My question is (because someone else and I argued the meaning of the girl's response):

What did the girl mean by "You. We’ll see about that :)"

Did she mean that she’s hesitant to see me?
Or did she mean that she wants to see me when she arrives home?

Throughout the conversation, flirtatious jabs were exchanged and said that she wished I was with her. (She’s abroad and has told me several times that "we’ll have October to ourselves".)

English is not my first language.

Comment: Is that the exact text that she sent you? Could you possibly provide a screenshot?

Comment: She is saying that she doesn't believe she'll never see you again.  What precisely this means would be highly dependent on the tone of voice and other clues.

Answer (score 3):

You say that:

> Mind you throughout the conversation flirtatious jabs were exchanged and she wished I was with her

This definitely influences the way that we should interpret the part that's confusing you. Let's take a look at what you said:

> ME - Hope she gets better and you’ll never ever have to see me or that hospital again

You are expressing a wish, and two expected outcomes of that wish. The wish is that the girl's mother gets better. The expected outcomes are that a.) the girl won't have to see the hospital again b.) she won't have to see *you* again.

Now we can look at her response to that:

> GIRL-Thanks. Hospital. Yeah. You. We’ll see about that :)

She is *very likely* expressing a wish to see you again in the future. Let's break up what she said.

First, she's thanking you for what I described as your wish above - that her mother will regain her health. Then, she's breaking up what you expressed as a single thought into two thoughts - you said "me or that hospital", lumping yourself with the hospital. She's now splitting "Hospital" on its own, separating it from *you*. So, that "Hospital. Yeah." is agreeing with your expected outcome of not having to see the hospital again.

Then she goes on to say "You. We'll see about that :)"

You said in your post that she said that she wished that you were with her. So what's she's saying with *this* is, after separating the hospital and you in your expected outcomes, she's saying that "We'll see about that :)" and disputing your expected outcome of not seeing you again. The smiley, which is a *happy* face, shows that she's not being pessimistic about her mother recovering, as [@Shoe claims](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/461784/112433) - if that were the case then a sad emoji would be appropriate.

So, all in all, everything points to her disputing your expected outcome of *not seeing you* after her mother is better, and is expressing a wish to see you again.

Comment: Adding a few question marks would really help in understanding her message: **Thanks. [The h]ospital? Yeah. You? We’ll see about that.**

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that your friend meant what you think she meant by the expression. But only she can know exactly what she was trying to tell you. It is not possible to ask her?

But note that *We’ll see about that!* can be used to express doubt about something someone has said. For example:

- Person 1: I promise I won't be late again.
- Person 2: Well, we'll see about that!

Person 2 is doubtful that Person 1 will keep her promise.

In your case, a possible interpretation of the exchange is that you have expressed the hope that you won't need to see your friend and her mother at the hospital again. Your friend is pessimistic and doesn't believe that her mother will get better. *We’ll see about that* expresses this pessimism.

Comment: I've tried to explain why I think that this answer is incorrect - and, so, my downvote - in [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/461787/112433).

Comment: @Mithrandir. You justify your different interpretation well. Unfortunately, we will never know which interpretation is correct, unless the OP asks the girl directly what she meant and reports back here. I've have edited my answer to add a bit of hedging.